# homomorphic groups without isomorphism

Tags: group-homomorphism

I am just trying to think about if the homomorphism $\delta$ between two groups can be undefined for some elements such as the id map from $\mathbb{Z} \; \mapsto \; \mathbb{N}$ thanks..
well because, I want an example without isomorphism between $\mathbf{G}_{ \; 1} \; / \; ker \; ( \; \delta \; )$ and $\mathbf{G}_{\; 2}$. That is all....

Comment: Just for the record: $\mathbb{N},$ whether or not $\mathbb{N}$ contains $0,$ is **not a group** under either $+$ or $\times$. For both $+$ and $\times,$ the number $2$ does not have an inverse (in $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Thanks Will R I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \colon G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism of groups. By the first isomorphism theorem you will always get an isomorphism $G/\text{ker}(f) \cong \text{im}(f)$, but in general you will not have $G/\text{ker}(f) \cong H$. An easy example would be an inclusion of finite groups $G \subset H$, where $G \neq H$. Then you will always have $G/\text{ker}(i) \not \cong H$ due to cardinality reasons. This example obviously also works with embeddings in the same way or with a finite subgroup of an infinite group.

As a concrete example, just consider the inclusion $\lbrace 0 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

In case that this does not answer your question: I am (apparantly) not sure what you are asking then.

Comment: help me please this is what I am reading now: Fundamental homomorphism theorem:
If $[ \; \alpha \; : \; 0 \; \hookrightarrow \; \mathbb{Z} \; ]$ is a group homomorphism,
$0 \subset [ \; ker \; ( \; \alpha \; ) \; = \; 0 \; ]$, and 
$[ \; \beta \; :\; 0 \; \rightarrow \; 0 \; / \; 0 \; ]$ is the canonical projection, then
$[ \; \delta \; :\; 0 \; / \; 0 \; \rightarrow \; Z \; ]$ is a homomorphism. Replacing m with the entire kernel gives the 1st isomorphism theorem. $0$ is the entire kernel so why can't I find any isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, $\delta \colon 0/0 = 0/\text{ker}(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective homomorphism then ($\alpha$ as well, but still). That means if you restrict the codomain to the image of $\alpha$, the map $\delta$ wil also be surjective and thus an isomorphism. As the image is just $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, we get $0/0 \cong 0$ here.

Comment: Thanks - _- Now I just have to find out about tensor products of *co*homology groups...……...